# Laravel throws NotFoundHttpException on a resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my URL:

```
http://serverHost:port/projectName/public/restaurants/create
```

This is the error message:

```
Open: UrlToProject\bootstrap\compiled.php
        if (!is_null($route)) {
            return $route->bind($request);
        }
        $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);
        if (count($others) > 0) {
            return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
        }
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
    protected function checkForAlternateVerbs($request)
```

Though the route does exist like this:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

and the controller `RestaurantsController` has this method:

```
public function create()
    {
        return View::make('restaurants.create');
    }
```

and the view absolutely exists. What am I doing wrong please?

I am working on Laravel 4.2.3 on Windows 7.

Also, I noticed these `lock` signs. is this wrong?

[image: Locked files and folders]

Comment: Where have you put the controller? Have you any namespace? Try `composer dump-autoload` in your console. Otherwise there must be a slip of the pen. Show us your controller code

Comment: @estshy I put the controller in the `controller` folder, and I already created the controller using the `artisan`. Plus, no I didn't try `composer dump-autoload` what is that please?

Comment: @estshy I tried executing that command on the root and then try to call the url and the same error happens

Comment: Code that you presented here hasn't any errors imho. Try to run `artisan serve` and access your website by default address localhost:8000 or whatever url Laravel give you.

Comment: @estshy the server is working and I can see the home page. but I have noticed something weird, I tried to make a simple route to a page and it gives me the same error, so the route is not working at all, maybe  i have to recompile? and  I see this `locked` sign on folders, I will edit the qeuestion to show it to you wait please

Comment: @estshy the problem was that the project name has a capital letter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself

The project name has a capital letter case and I was calling it small letter :)